# How do you say "Hunter x Hunter"?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I read somewhere that the author says that you don't say, "Hunter by Hunter" or "Hunter vs Hunter" but "Hunter hunter". You say it twice in progression. Is this correct?

Here's the [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HunterxHunter) from Wikipedia (under the Production section):

> He came up with the final name Hunter × Hunter while watching the
>   television variety show Downtown, in which the hosts often repeated
>   what they said to make the audience laugh.

Comment: I've always heard people call it "hunter ecks hunter", personally. I can't comment on the "official" pronunciation, though.

Comment: That's the way I've been saying as well. I'll see if I can find the reference from the author. Found it. See post.

Comment: I don't watch the show, and I don't have access to it here at work, but I've found some people saying that the post-credit previews have it verbally said as "hunter hunter".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's Hunter (silent x) Hunter according to the show's creator; Yoshihiro Togashi

For additional proof, the episode titles all include the same stylised x's:

- Test × of × Tests
- Rivals × for × Survival
- Hisoka × is × Sneaky, etc.

Which would make no sense if you said them with the x's

Comment: This is a cultural affectation of Japanese and Chinese language structures. Saying a word twice can give a greater emphasis to the word.

Comment: @Thaddeus - Moshi Moshi

Comment: @Valorum Mushi shi Mushi shi